# Why the command echo php print badly lines html?

Tags: php, html, echo, carriage-return

I am new on the php but I am trying to build a page that produces after having read something from the database the inherent checkboxes, but when these are printed with echo the formatting it is not the desired one producing therefore of the errors for the carriage return. 
Here is the php

```
<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query="SELECT * FROM ingrediente";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   $name = $row["id_ingrediente"];
   $value = $row["immagine"];
   $etichetta = $row["nome"];
   $prezzo = $row["costo_unitario"];
    echo "\n";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name=$name value='$value' onchange=\"add_ing2($name,'$value','$etichetta',$prezzo,this);\">$etichetta" ;
    echo "\n";
    echo "<input type='number' name='$etichetta' style='border:0px; text-align:right;background:transparent; height:auto;' value=$prezzo readonly> €";
    echo "\n";
    echo "<br><br>";

  }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Here is the produced html

```
<input type='checkbox' name=1 value='/images/ingredienti/pomodoro.png' onchange="add_ing2(1,'/images/ingredienti/pomodoro.png','Pomodoro',0.3,this);">Pomodoro
<input type='number' name='Pomodoro' style='border:0px; text-align:right;background:transparent; height:auto;' value=0.3 readonly> €
<br><br>
<input type='checkbox' name=2 value='/images/ingredienti/formaggio.png
' onchange="add_ing2(2,'/images/ingredienti/formaggio.png
','Formaggio',0.2,this);">Formaggio
<input type='number' name='Formaggio' style='border:0px; text-align:right;background:transparent; height:auto;' value=0.2 readonly> €
<br><br>
<input type='checkbox' name=3 value='/images/ingredienti/hamburger.png
' onchange="add_ing2(3,'/images/ingredienti/hamburger.png
','Hamburger',1,this);">Hamburger
<input type='number' name='Hamburger' style='border:0px; text-align:right;background:transparent; height:auto;' value=1 readonly> €
<br><br>
```

As you can see the correct way to print has been applied only to the first element (Pomodoro (line 1:2 in html code)). Since this causes me more than few problems when then use the checkboxes, as can I resolve?

Thank you so much

Comment: Wrong assumption! Your `$value` seems too have an line-break at the end. You can see that the line breaks after the image url. So look for an `\n` at the image value. Tip: `$value = trim($value);` [update] Do `trim()` on all used variables.

Comment: Looks like you've got bad data with newlines in it. Take a look in the database - I'll bet you'll see them there in the raw data. You can try `trim()`ing the values, but better to fix the underlying issue.

Comment: And before asked: `value=$prezzo` misses the single quotes `value='$prezzo'`

Comment: I applied the trim() to all the variables and it works!!! thx so much to everybody <3 post this as an answer <3

Comment: You should probably fix whatever script you use to load the data into the DB, so it trims the newlines at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with PHP - the data you're pulling out of the database is just bad. Some of your image paths have a new-line character at the end.

You should ultimately fix the data (validating user input, adjusting scripts that pull it in automatically, etc.), but you can apply `trim()` to the values to strip off the extra character(s).

Answer (score 0):

> Wrong assumption! Your $value seems too have an line-break at the end.
>   You can see that the line breaks after the image url. So look for an
>   \n at the image value. Tip: $value = trim($value); [update] Do trim()
>   on all used variables. – 
>   @JustOnUnderMillions
>
> Looks like you've got bad data with newlines in it. Take a look in the
>   database - I'll bet you'll see them there in the raw data. You can try
>   trim()ing the values, but better to fix the underlying issue. –
>   @ceejayoz

I applied the trim() to all the variables and it works!!! Thx so much JustOnUnderMillion and ceejayox <3